# Is Process Monitor able to pick up when a "system sound"(one of those wav files), plays? I'm using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, process-monitor

Is (sysinternals) Process Monitor able to pick up when a "system sound"(one of those wav files), plays? I'm using Windows 7

[image]

I tried this filter "ends with"  "wav" but it's not picking it up

[image]

I tried triggering the WAV by clicking the "test" button in "system sounds" as shown in the window shown in one of the pics above.

And by clicking the back and forward buttons in the explorer window below

[image]

They play the sound. But it's not getting detected by process monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't, because it's not played by an external application. It's coded directly into Windows or applications. It's created with PlaySound function, which spews it directly to the audio driver.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)